Hardhat returning incorrect call results in chai tests
I'm currently facing a problem with hardhat tests, where the result of a call to a contract in the test returns incorrect results. The following contract is an example of where this might occur:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Temp {
    enum MsgTag {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }

    struct Msg {
        MsgTag tag;
        bytes data;
    }

    enum ReturnMsgTag {
        Int,
        Bool,
        String
    }

    struct ReturnMsg {
        ReturnMsgTag tag;
        bytes data;
    }

    function messageHandler(Msg memory msg) public returns (ReturnMsg memory) {
        if (msg.tag == MsgTag.A) {
            return ReturnMsg(ReturnMsgTag.Int, abi.encode(123));
        } else if (msg.tag == MsgTag.B) {
            return ReturnMsg(ReturnMsgTag.Bool, abi.encode(true));            
        } else if (msg.tag == MsgTag.C) {
            return ReturnMsg(ReturnMsgTag.String, abi.encode("Hello, World!"));
        }
    }
}

(I realise this is a very artificial example and there are better ways of accomplishing what this contract does, it is just a simplification of my more complex use case, where I cannot get around working with enums and bytes).
When passing [0, "0x"] (indicating a Msg of type A) in remix, the decoded result of the call is the following:
0,0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b

When attempting to call this function in a hardhat test case, with the same input, the result is the following (which cannot be decoded back into a (uint8, bytes)):
0x06521e4b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This is the test setup I'm currently employing to test and fetch this information:
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Main Contract", function () {
    let MainContract;
    let mainContract;

    let AbiCoder;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        AbiCoder = new ethers.AbiCoder()

        MainContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Temp");
        mainContract = await MainContract.deploy(); 

        console.log(await mainContract.messageHandler([0, "0x"]));
    });

    describe("MessageHandler", function () {
        it("Should handle messages correctly", async function () {
            let res = await mainContract.messageHandler([0, "0x"]);
            expect(AbiCoder.decode(["uint8", "bytes"], res.data)[0] ).to.equal(0);
        });
    });
});

Am I wrong in assuming the output in remix and the output in hardhat should be the same? If so, is there any other way I can verify and test the output of functions outputting such types in these tests?
